# Flask: the way closing database connections, will it able to handle high traffic?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I need to create 20 APIs for the use of my app. These APIs, will fetch data from my MySQL database. Since I expected the **traffic** will be fairly high at peak hours (peak hours only 2 hours), and may get 30 to 50 request per second.

What I am concern is the connections. Since only 3 connections is allows at one time, with the method I close cursors and database will able to handle high traffic and user able to access 20 APIs with no issues? The data I fetch is small, as my whole database in text is just merely 2MB.

If this method can handle high traffic, I will not want to switch to sqlalchemy.

```
# A very simple Flask Hello World app for you to get started with...

from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response,request,render_template
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/MUSIC', methods=['GET'])
def Music():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='doreme.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='doreme',passwd='pw',db='doreme$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    curs = db.cursor()
    try:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM MUSIC")
        a = curs.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    finally:
        curs.close()
        db.close()
    return jsonify({'Music': a})

@app.route('/MUSICKorea', methods=['GET'])
def MusicKorea():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='doreme.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='doreme',passwd='pw',db='doreme$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    curs = db.cursor()
    try:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM MusicKorea")
        b = curs.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    finally:
        curs.close()
        db.close()
    #return "hihi"
    return jsonify({'Song': b})

@app.route('/MUSICKorea/<Item>', methods=['GET'])
def Musicitem(Korea):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='doreme.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='doreme',passwd='pw',db='doreme$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM MUSIC WHERE Song LIKE %s",(Korea,))
        c = curs.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    finally:
        curs.close()
        db.close()
    return jsonify({'Korea': c})
```

Comment: Why don't you just measure the time it takes via `timeit`?

Comment: @MrLeeh, How I should measure it? Any suggestion? time from connection open to close?

Comment: Just measure the time it takes for your function to supply the data, like shown by @Maurice_Meyer.

Comment: However I would suggest to use only one global connection and share it between the routes. This way you won't need to reconnect every time.

Comment: @MrLeeh, could you explain more how to apply global connection to my app?

Comment: Just put the declaration of your db variable straight und your app declaration and don't close the database in each function.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily test your wsgi application using a http benchmark tool (ab, wrk, ... more tools are listed [here](https://gist.github.com/denji/8333630)).

Measure the time taken of your python functions and/or the mysql queries (very simple, timeit might be better):

```
import time
...

@app.route('/MUSICKorea/<Item>', methods=['GET'])
def Musicitem(Korea):
    t = time.time()
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='doreme.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='doreme',passwd='pw',db='doreme$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    print('connecting took %.6f seconds' % (time.time()-t))
    try:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM MUSIC WHERE Song LIKE %s",(Korea,))
        c = curs.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    finally:
        curs.close()
        db.close()
    print('Musicitem took %.6f seconds' % (time.time()-t))
    return jsonify({'Korea': c})
```

Comment: If the time take is 0.2s, does it mean I can allow 5 different request thru the API to query from MySQL at max?

Comment: run [ab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench), that will tell you how many requests are served per second.